# Using Core image filters for images

Tags: iphone, filter, ios5, core-image

I have used core image framework for adding image filters in my project.The first five filters that I have added are working correctly.But when I implement other filters.The image goes off.The filters that work are:
1)CIHueAdjust
2)CIGammaAdjust
3)CIExposureAdjust
4)CIColorMonochrome
5)CISepiaTone
The other filters that didnt work for me are the CIGloom,CILineOverlay and others.Here is my code.Plz help me were I am wrong.....

```
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"leaves2.png"]];
CIFilter *Gloom = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGloom"];
[Gloom setDefaults];
[Gloom setValue: inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[Gloom setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 10.00]
                  forKey:@"inputRadius"];[Gloom setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 0.8f]
         forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
CIImage *outputImage = [Gloom valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
// define context
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
// set image to UIImageView
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:
                   [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                 fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
```

When I click the button.The image goes off.

Comment: Does `Gloom` get a valid pointer in the assignment on the second line?

Comment: Yes.It gets.It works for other filters.But for certain filters,it doesnt

Comment: When the image returns.It is null.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 doesn't include all of the Core Image filters that Mac OS X does... CIGloom and CILineOverlay are Mac only.

You can get an array of all of the available filter names in iOS 5 by calling this:

```
NSArray *filterNamesArray = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategories:[NSArray arrayWithObject:kCICategoryBuiltIn]];
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html where you can find details about the available filters @Kumaresh

Comment: @Bala You linked to the mac documents.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html